# How to name file at run-time in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, filenames, wav

I need my MATLAB function to modify the input file name (which I am passing as input argument to the function) each time I run it.
For example, if I pass input arguments like this: `func_name('file.wav')` to my function func_name, then how do I write a code to save a new file named **filenew.wav**?
While .wav is the extension for sound files.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? How to modify the input name, or how to write a wav-file?

Comment: How to modify the input name and save it as a new file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) to seperate the path, file name and extension.

You may also find `fullfile` command to be useful to create the new file name with path.